# Missing library versions required by VSCode remote server running on Raspberry Pi

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, remote-server

Attempting remote development with VSCode 1.43.2 hosted on Darwin 18.7.0.

SSH target is a Raspberry Pi3 running raspbian jesse.

`uname -a` reports `"Linux 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux"`

gcc version is `gcc version 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10+deb8u2)`

The remote server code installed automatically but fails to start with the following error messages.

```
> Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/pi/.vscode-server/.0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50.log >>>
> /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/node)
> /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/node)
> <<< End of server log
```

/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 exists on the Pi.

What do I need to do to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

The version of your C++ standard library (libstdc++.so.6) is simply too old, a newer version is required to run VSCode Server. 
You could probably add some backports or third-party repositories to upgrade it, but IMHO, it's not worth the hassle.

Raspbian Jessie is old, and Debian Jessie will no longer be supported after June 30, 2020.
The best thing to do is just upgrading to Raspbian Buster.

Comment: That may well be the best approach (or else give up on vscode remote for now).  I'll wait a few days to see if someone has managed to solve it for Jessie before marking your answer accepted.